# Django Queryset access by index issue

Tags: django

I have a Client model with a created_at field. I want to update the created_at for a client from the shell. I did the following:

```
>>> c = Client.objects.all()
>>> c[1].created_at
>>> # I get nothing here since it's not set yet
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> c[1].created_at = timezone.now()
>>> c[1].save()
>>> c[1].created_at
>>> # I still get nothing here. Even when I reload the queryset, I get nothing.
```

However, when I do the same thing with `c = Client.object.get(id=1)`, it works. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign the queryset object to its own istance and then it will save, what you're doing above is just editing the queryset item

```
c = Client.objects.all()
obj = c[1]
obj.created_at = timezone.now()
obj.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that works. Why does this happen though? I'm so confused.

Comment: it's because the objects in a Queryset aren't saved in memory and the queryset is just a copy of the objects. To get the actual object (i.e. to be able to update it and save it) you need to assign it to a variable in memory

Comment: Not really; it's because every slice operation does a new query to the database and returns a new object. So the first `c[1]` is not connected to subsequent ones.